# Confused with conditional and logical operators - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, logical-operators, comparison-operators

I'm kind of new to VB.net, and since I just finished a C# course, the lack of parentheses creates a lot of confusion on how to write certain combinations of operators.

The C# equivalent of the line I am trying to reproduce in VB would be like this :

```
if ( (a == 0 && b != null) || (a == 1 && c != null) )
```

I'm have no idea how to write this in VB, I've tried many combinations of And, Or, AndAlso, OrElse, etc. but I can't achieve the desired result.

I can't find any clear example of C# v.s. VB.net comparison on operators, and the notes I have aren't helpful either.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: You meant if ( (a == 0 && b != null) || (a == 1 && c != null) ) Note the `==`

Comment: I see from other commnents that the lack of parentheses is a teacher required impairment, and that you know the language supports them.  Did he give any justification for this? Some condition will be quite complex, or outright impossible, to do w/o parans due to operator precedence.  3+3\2 is not the same as (3+3)\2.  Splitting the expression into multiple expressions is a solution, but will mean you are doing the compilers job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equals operator is `==` in C# and `=` in VB.

```cs
if ( (a == 0 && b != null) || (a == 1 && c != null) )
    statement; // One single statement only
```

or

```cs
if ( (a == 0 && b != null) || (a == 1 && c != null) ) {
    statement; // Any number of statements
}
```

This online [conversion tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) will convert it to VB for you:

```vb
If (a = 0 AndAlso b IsNot Nothing) OrElse (a = 1 AndAlso c IsNot Nothing) Then
    statement
End If
```

C# `&&` translates to `AndAlso` in VB.
C# `||` translates to `OrElse` in VB.

With these operators the evaluation stops as soon as the result is determined. This is known as "short-circuit" evaluation. E.g. in `a && b` the result is known to be `false` if `a` is `false`, and `b` will not be evaluated. This is especially important when the evaluation has side effects, like performing database queries, raising events or modifying data. It is also useful in conditions like these `person != null && person.Name == "Doe"` where the second would throw an exception if the first term evaluates to `false`.

---

The equivalent of the VB `And` and `Or` Boolean operators that do not use short-circuit evaluation are `&` and `|` in C#. Here all the terms will always be evaluated.

```vb
If (a = 0 Or b = 0 And c = 0) Then
    statement
End If
```

```
if (a = 0 | b = 0 & c = 0) {
    statement;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant ==, another confusing thing when switching between both languages. Also, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

The vb.net equivalent would be

```
If (a = 0 AndAlso b IsNot Nothing) OrElse (a = 1 AndAlso c IsNot Nothing ) Then
```

Note in c#, it should be `a == 0` and not `a = 0`

Checkout [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/vbnet_c__difference.aspx) with a comprehensive comparison.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` instead of just `And` and `Or`?

Comment: @PaulStock C# && is short-circuited and it's equivalent is AndAlso.

Comment: Yes, 'And' and 'Or' do not function the same way in VB.

Comment: @PaulStock And and Or are VB's binary operator equivalent to C#'s & and |

Answer (score 0):

if ( (a = 0 && b != null) || (a = 1 && c != null) )

Is equivilent to:

if ( ( a = 0 AndAlso b IsNot Nothing) OrElse (a = 1 AndAlso c IsNot Nothing) )

Comment: I haven't tested it, but that is from my memory.  In the future you might want to try some of the code conversion tools, some of them are quite accurate, and most of them you can just post code snippets to online.  Google c# to vb or something similar.

Comment: Well the teacher doesn't want us to use any parentheses in If's, but thanks anyway, it seems to do the trick. Also, for "a != null", he told us to use "Not a Is Nothing", which is kind of confusing, so thanks for telling about the IsNot.

Comment: Most programmers will not write a conditional statement that is so convoluted in the first place if they can avoid it.  You can tell your teacher that inverting negatively phrased conditionals is a standard refactoring and is espoused in many books on proper clean coding =)  That being said, if your teacher gives you a test...fill it out the way that he/she told you.